# Probabilities in copula doesn't sum up to 1

Tags: r

I am generating a matrix of probabilities from a bivariate gaussian copula with poisson marginals. I can't figure out why probabilities doesn't add to 1 but to slightly more. Here is the code:

```
library(copula) 

cop<-normalCopula(param = 0.92, dim = 2)
mv <- mvdc(cop, c("pois", "pois"),list(list(lambda = 6), list(lambda = 4)))

m <- matrix(NA,50,50)
for (i in 0:49) {
  for (j in 0:49) {
    m[i+1,j+1]=dMvdc(c(i,j),mv)
  }
}

sum(m)
[1] 1.048643
```

EDIT: It seems that this problem is present only when the `param` parameter (the correlation) is different from 0.

Comment: Not sure why they would sum to one? If you do the same with simple normal distribution `sum(dnorm(c(-0.1,0,0.1)))` that won't sum to one either. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The normal distribution is continuous, so the density clearly doesn't sum to 1. But for a discrete distribution, the sum of the density of all the outcomes need to sum to 1.

Comment: Is there a chance that you have rounding influencing the final sum introduced in your loop?

Comment: I don't think so, I have this problem just when the correlation is different from zero. When is zero the sum is exactly one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `dMvdc` does:

[image: distribution]

Here [image: c] is the density of your copula, [image: fi] are the probability densities of your choice (in this case `dpois`), and [image: Fi] are the corresponding cdf's (in this case `ppois`).

For this to represent a valid probability distribution, i.e. to integrate to 1, you need to be able to do the final substitution below, which requires continuous probability distributions:

[image: finalformula]

If you use discrete pdf's (via Dirac deltas):

[image: dirac]

the above will generally fail:

[image: fail]

which is what you observed.

The 0 correlation case works accidentally, because in that case [image: c] is simply the identity function:

```
dCopula(c(runif(1), runif(1)), normalCopula(0))
#[1] 1
```

I'm not sure if the copula can be normalized appropriately to salvage the non-zero correlation case.

Comment: I think `pois` is perfectly accepted as argument, indeed simulating from a poisson gives correct results

Comment: Yes, it is accepted as an argument, *with the assumption* that `dpois` and `qpois` represent a continuous distribution. `mvdc` doesn't check what those functions do, it just uses them.

Comment: @adiana I added some clarification

Comment: Is there a way to use copulas with discrete marginals?

Comment: I mean that if I normalize `m`, the marginals are not anymore poisson. So the trick helps if you want `m` to sum to 1 but you haven't got poisson marginals

Comment: One usually uses copula to keep the marginals of a given form, with your trick the marginals are not anymore poisson so that doesn't help me. I am getting the marginals just from the normalized matrix `m/sum(m)`

Comment: Just sum over a component to obtain the marginal of the other component.

Comment: Yes, it is instead. Try generating values with a copula with zero-correlation and compute the marginal and you will note that they are exactly two poissons.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to say. My objection is that the marginals are not anymore poisson with your trick to renormalize, so it won't work for my purposes.

Comment: The marginals have the same form as the initial marginals, try using this code: `samp <- rMvdc(100000,mv)` and you will see that every marginal is actually a poisson

Comment: You're right, I forgot that copulas are supposed to have marginals that are uniform. I'm not sure if the discrete case is salvageable - if it is, it'll require modifying the copula somehow.

Comment: I'm a little confused about it right now - will take another look later.

Comment: Don't worry, thank you for helping. I will give a +1 and accept anyway

Comment: To make it work, you need to replace the continuous copula with a discrete one, where the value at each point is equal to the integral over the integer square around it, which is exactly the differences of `pnorm` as you mentioned earlier.